# Pass a string value to a cell on a different table view controller

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uitableview

I am new to Xcode, and I have been using examples I have found to try to make sense of it. I am trying to make an app that would take information from a QR Code and send that information to a table view.I would like to pass this value

`[_qrCode performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];`

From a UIViewController (QRCodeViewController) to a Cell of a TableViewController (PatientTableViewController)  that is using core data.

If you need more info let me know.
Thanks Again for any Help.

Comment: What background are you coming from? Seems like I need to know that before I can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the QR Code Scanning controller presented modally on top of the Table View?

You'll probably want to insert a new `NSManagedObject` into your context from the scanning controller, and when the table view becomes visible again, you refresh your fetched results controller. This way the Core Data context remains consistent and the controllers don't need to be aware of each other.